# Python lxml problems with idref()?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xslt, lxml

Hello community, unfortunately I have a problem with an XSLT or the Python XML parser lxml. I have a DTD validated XML and I want to use an XSLT to find all IDREF of an ID . Below is a sample XML and the XSLT.

XML 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEST
[
<!ELEMENT TEST (N*,SUB*)>
<!ELEMENT N (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT SUB (E*)>
<!ELEMENT E (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST TEST

>
<!ATTLIST SUB

>
<!ATTLIST N
    Id                  ID          #REQUIRED
    X                   CDATA       #REQUIRED
>
<!ATTLIST E
    EID                 ID          #REQUIRED
    N1                  IDREF       #REQUIRED
    N2                  IDREF       #REQUIRED
>
]>
<TEST>
    <N Id="N1" X="0.0"/>
    <N Id="N2" X="1.0"/>
    <N Id="N3" X="2.0"/>
    <N Id="N4" X="3.0"/>
    <SUB>
        <E EID="E1" N1="N1" N2="N2"/>   
        <E EID="E2" N1="N1" N2="N3"/>
        <E EID="E3" N1="N1" N2="N4"/>
    </SUB>
</TEST>
```

XSLT 1.0 (

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
<xsl:template match="//N">
    <xsl:element name="NREF"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="**idref('N1')**">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My example python script parses the XML and the XSLT, transforms the XML and writes the result to a new file.

Python 3.9

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

xml_parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(  attribute_defaults=True, dtd_validation =True, no_network=False)
xml_root  = lxml.etree.parse('XML.xml', parser=xml_parser)
xslt_root = lxml.etree.parse('id_idref_test.xslt')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
result_tree = transform(xml_root)
result_tree.write(f"XML_Result.xml",method="xml",pretty_print=True)
```

Now about my problem. Xpath supports the functions `id()` and `idref()`. When I use the `id('N1')` function in the loop I get the following result.`<NREF>N</NREF>`. If I use the `idref('N1')` function I get an error from the parser. `lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.`  Is the `idref()` function not implemented in the lxml scope?

I hope I can explain my problem in sufficient detail. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `idref()` function requires XPath/XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Comment: Hi Mr michael.hor257k, thanks for the quick reply. 
However, the id() function is present in Xpath 1.0, do I see that correctly?

Comment: Yes, the `id()` function is part of XPath 1.0. But the `idref() `function is not. You say that you get an error when using the  `idref() `function, but not when using the `id()` function - just as expected.

Comment: Ah okay. I understood that then. thanks for the help

Comment: I would suggest you use the [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) mechanism to resolve cross-references. This works in XSLT 1.0 and does not require a DTD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The idref() function requires XPath/XSLT 2.0 or higher.* Thanks to michael.hor257k